# Average file size statistics

Tags: windows, filesystems

Is there any way to calculate, and breakdown, average file sizes for a given directory (or drive)?

Something that can give details such as:|

- Files of 4KB - 22KB: account to 20% of all files
- Files of 32KB - 64KB: account to 10% of all files
- Files of 1MB - 20MB: account to 70% of all files

And so on.

Perhaps you know of a utility that can do that?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this pretty easily in Powershell

```powershell
$items = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\your\file\path" -recurse
$count = ($items | measure-object | select -expand Count)
$size = (($items | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum /1MB)
$avrg = $size / $count
$avrg
```

**Output example:**

```
PS X:\> $avrg
1.03643417358398
```

Comment: the first line can be shortened to `(ls "c:\your\file\path" -r | measure-object).Count`

Comment: Note that $foot is the number of files and $bar is the total size of all the files in MB. Also, you can calculate the size of files with only a certain extension by putting a *.ext at the end of the both (both paths need to be modified)

Answer (score 2):

Someone over at [Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/261860-average-file-size-statistics.html) pointed me out to Agent Ransack from Mythicsoft:

http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home

Had to make the calculations on my own but it wasn't so bad.

Answer (score 2):

One-liner for getting the most basic stats

```
Get-ChildItem . -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -Average -Maximum -Minimum
```

Output:

```
Count    : 368672
Average  : 498118,454393065
Sum      : 183642326818
Maximum  : 157928130
Minimum  : 1
Property : Length
```

If you are on PS v6 or later, you also have a `StandardDeviation` field. Or simply provide `-AllStats` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I just used total commander (shareware) and microsoft excel to do that in 2 minutes.

In Total Commander go to the root of C: (or any drive you like) click Ctrl+B, which lists all files within all subdirectories in one place. From Mark menu item, click "Copy to clipboard with all details" and paste into excel... you now have a long list of items with their file sizes, sort and count to your hearts content. You can also Google "histogram in Excel" for a nicer output.

What I ended up with on a one-year-old Windows 8.1 system is shown below (sizes are in bytes, and the x axis figures are my defined range).  As one can see majority of my files are around 1k range.

[image: The x axis figures are my defined range]

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this is helpful](http://windirstat.info/)?

WinDirStat is slow, but accurate, I don't know for sure if it averages files in a directory.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried it. It doesn't report the information I need - the closest it get's is dividing the folder contents by file extension which is irrelevant for me